# I get HTTP ERROR 405 when I try to add a new record to my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm making a website with asp.net core and Angular and I'm trying to add a new record in a database in SQL Server.
It works when I want to display the content of the database, but it doesn't when I try to add a new record.

I was trying to do it in different ways, but always that I try to add something, I get HTTP ERROR 405.
I don't really know what could be wrong, I was checking some ways to fix and nothing what I tried works.

Thank you in advance!

This is the method that is adding new users:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> Register(string username, string password){

            using var hmac = new HMACSHA512();

            var user = new Users{
                username = username,
                PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)),
                PasswordSalt = hmac.Key
            };

            _context.Users.Add(user);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return user;
        }
```

Comment: HTTP 405 has nothing to do with the code you show, but the code that is calling your API. I guess you are doing an HTTP POST instead of a GET for example.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add a new User doing HttpPost.

Comment: But this method is expecting a `GET`, not a `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Adds the attribute `[HttpPost]` over this method if you want to call doing a POST

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed it". It was actually working, but it was not possible to see it directly on the explorar. I had to use swagger.
But thank you all anyways!